# Is there any document or example for using GetX navigation 2.0

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, flutter-getx, flutter-navigation

I need to update my navigation code to getx Navigation 2.0 which is very easy to use in flutter web

Comment: https://github.com/search?q=getx+navigation

Using Github's search feature you might find project examples.

Comment: No, i didn't get answer for my question there